# How to disable the auto gain control in android phone?

Tags: audio-recording, voice-recording, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

Audio recording quality in Redme note 4 (sdk) is very low. Voice get clear for the first second and then lower down its volume automatically. How to cop up this issue.